# SSMTP with gmail "cannot open 587:587"

Tags: email, gmail, ssmtp

I'm trying to configure my HTPC to send me an email once in a while, particularly after certain cron jobs but I can't get it to work. I've also got a server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS where I eventually got SSMTP to work so I've tried to copy those settings (ssmtp.conf) but to no avail. When trying to send an email from CLI, I get an error message saying `ssmtp: Cannot open 587:587`

```
#ssmtp.conf 
hostname=HTPC
Root=username@gmail.com
Mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
RewriteDomain=gmail.com
AuthUser=username
AuthPass=password
FromLineOverride=Yes
UseTLS=Yes
```

```
#revalias 
root:username@gmail.com:587
username:username@gmail.com:587
```

I've googled a fair bit and found a bugreport regarding SSMTP and Gmail where the certificates were to blame, the suggestion was to add `TLS_CA_File=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` to my `ssmtp.conf` file. I've tried that but when checking the directory, there is no `ca-certificates.crt`file there and the error message is the same.

I also tried using port 465 instead, replacing 587 in bort `ssmtp.conf`and `revaliases` but the error stays the same, `ssmtp: Cannot open 465:465`

```
#/var/log/syslog
Sep 22 18:11:32 HTPC sSMTP[2157]: Unable to set TLS_CA_File="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
Sep 22 18:11:36 HTPC sSMTP[2157]: Unable to connect to "587" port 587.
Sep 22 18:11:36 HTPC sSMTP[2157]: Cannot open 587:587
```

That second to last line in `syslog` confuses me. Anyone?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Kodi is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: Kodi? Who said anything about Kodi? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the entries in `revaliases` are wrong:

```
root:username@gmail.com:587
```

should rather be

```
root:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

and accordingly for the other aliases.